# Создание шаблона xml layout на android

Tags: android, xml, шаблоны, layout, календарь

Хочу создать android-приложение (условно календарь с событиями). Главный экран будет представлять собой ScrollView с днями (LinearLayout). При первом открытии приложения главный экран будет заполняться днями текущего месяца и соответственно на каждом будет дата.

Так вот, я хочу создать один xml-файл, который будет являться шаблоном для всех дней. Сначала пробовал без установки нового id. Но тогда число устанавливалась лишь для первого layout. Теперь проблема в том, что при установке нового id некорректно работает атрибут toRightOf в xml-файле.
Подозреваю, что есть более цивилизованный способ сделать то, что мне нужно, но о котором я не знаю.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

В методе onCreate главного файла запускается цикл создания дней:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
    Day day = new Day(this, i, 0, 2018, layout, getLayoutInflater());
}
```

Код дня:

```
public class Day extends RelativeLayout { //код "дня"
    private ActCell[] cells;
    GregorianCalendar date;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    LinearLayout layout;
    int id;

public Day(Context context, int day, int month, int year, LinearLayout layout, LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
    super(context);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    cells = new ActCell[30];
    date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.set(year, month, day);
    createDay();
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void createDay() {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.day, layout);

    TextView dayView = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    String stringMainID = Integer.toString(Calendar.DATE) + Integer.toString(Calendar.MONTH) + Integer.toString(Calendar.YEAR);
    id = Integer.parseInt(stringMainID);
    dayView.setId(id);
    dayView.setText(Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.DATE)));

    TextView monthView = view.findViewById(R.id.monthYear);
    String stringMonthID = Integer.toString(Calendar.MONTH) + Integer.toString(Calendar.YEAR);
    monthView.setId(Integer.parseInt(stringMonthID));
    monthView.setText(Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "." + Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

    TextView dayOfWeekView = view.findViewById(R.id.dayOfWeek);
    String stringDayOfWeekID = stringMainID + Integer.toString(1);
    dayOfWeekView.setId(Integer.parseInt(stringDayOfWeekID));
    dayOfWeekView.setText(date.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()));
}}

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="29"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="07.2018" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayOfWeek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="воскресенье"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Добавил изображение результата.]

Comment: А день то, последний только отображается ?

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863649/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-9%D1%859-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-textview-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: @Segrei Ulanov добавил изображение того, что получилось. То есть дни отобрааются все, но некорректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать RecyclerView. Вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) вы можете посмотреть краткое руководство по его применению.