# Создать идентичные 9х9 элементов TextView в виде таблички - с равными размерами

Tags: android, android-textview, android-linearlayout, height, width

У меня есть компоновка `LinearLayout` вертикальной ориентации, в которой находятся 9 компоновок `LinearLayout` горизонтальной ориентации, в каждой из которых по 9 `TextView` (итого 9 * 9 = **81** элемент `TextView`). Для грамотной реализации этого *творчества* я создаю по 9 горизонтальных компоновок `LinearLayout` и по 9 `TextView` в каждой из них в Java-коде, а затем, соответственно, добавляю их в основную компоновку компонента `Activity` примерно так:

```
for (int y = 8; y >= 0; y--) {
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout_row = ...//компоновка горизонтальной ориентации
    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        TextView mTextView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mtextview, ...
        mLinearLayout_row.addView(mMTextView);
    }
    myMainActivityLayout.addView(mLinearLayout_row, 0);
}
```

Все компоновки имеют длину `MATCH_PARENT`, а высоту `WRAP_CONTENT`. Вот код `mtextview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="X"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

На экране ширИны всех элементов `TextView` выглядят равными (если не вглядываться). Но на самом деле система Android задаёт ширину нескольким последним элементам с правой стороны во всех рядах чуть меньшую ширину - это система вычисляет алгоритмом за счёт известного значения атрибута `layout_weight` у всех `TextView`.

Теперь перейду к проблеме. У меня не получается сделать элементы `TextView` квадратными, таблица выглядит приплюснутой.

[image: default]

Я пробовал следующие способы:

1. Использовать *кастомный* `TextView`, в классе которого переопределив метод `onMeasure`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
   }
   ```

   Метод очень плох, так как элементы то делаются квадратными, но слева они большие, а справа маленькие - это очень некрасиво выглядит.

   [image: method1]
2. Использовать *кастомную* основную компоновку `LinearLayout`, в классе которой переопределив метод `onMeasure` (так же, как в п.1) и установив значение атрибута `layout_height` у `TextView` на `match_parent` - вообще никаких изменений.
3. В коде компонента `Activity`, в которой *всё это происходит*, переопределить метод `onResume`, в котором пытаться получить ширину всех `TextView` и задать им высоту, равную известной ширине... в общем-то способ не профессиональный и не оптимальный, по моему мнению, но, несмотря на это, я попробовал использовать этот способ, а оказалось, что, когда вызывается метод `onResume` система ещё не знает ширину элементов!!! (значение функции `mTextView.getWidth()`, полученное в этом методе равно 0).

---

Сожалею, что нереально тяжело *въехать,* в чём же у меня заключается проблема, но я постарался максимально подробно и корректно описать её :).

Comment: Можете показать скриншот?

Comment: Один из вариантов это использовать RecyclerView, где элементом будет одна TextView. И добавить ему layoutManager  =  GridLayoutManager, который будет для 9 элементов в ряд

Comment: @danilshik, да. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: `GridLayout`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843605/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8/843612#843612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать ячейки масшатбируемыми и квадратными, можно использовать свойство соотношения сторон `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` в `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_count_label"
    style="@style/AppThemeTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="@{formItem.stringValue}"
    android:textColor="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, formItem.color)}"
    android:textSize="@dimen/base"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_label" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это позволит вам сделать ячейки квадратными, вне зависимости от расширения экрана, т.к. они просто ужмутся по высоте и ширине

Но я предлагаю пойти вам дальше и переверстать экран с помощью recyclerView (как предложил Виталий в комментариях). Во-первых, это избавит вас от проблемы адресации к этим ячейкам, ведь их нужно будет заполнять и считывать. А во-вторых, реализация с RecycelerView будет эстетичнее (в разметке RecyclerView + адаптер + ViewHolder - вы сами убедитесь в простоте такой реализации). Установив размер 1 в item RecyclerView, вы автоматически его установите всем ячейкам.

Адаптер для RecyclerView стандартный, но нужно переопределить LayouManager. Создаете `LayoutManager`, наследуете его от `GridLayoutManager` (можно внутри адаптера):

```
private static class NonScrollableGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

    NonScrollableGridLayoutManager(Context context, int span) {
        super(context, span);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

В адаптере создаете метод, возвращающий объект `LayoutManager`:

```
public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager getLayoutManager(Context context) {
    return new NonScrollableGridLayoutManager(context, COUNT_OF_ITEM_IN_LINE);
}
```

Затем устанавливаете для `RecyclerView` ваш `LayoutManager`:

```
binding.monthContent.setLayoutManager(CalendarAdapter.getLayoutManager(
        binding.getRoot().getContext()));
binding.monthContent.setAdapter(daysAdapter);
binding.monthContent.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Не правда ли удобно?

Comment: Я целый день ботал и сумел таки решить эту проблему при помощи *легендарных атрибутов `layout_margin`!!* Я всё же сохранил структуру основной компоновки, почему же я сразу не догадался просто вычислить предполагаемую ширину `TextView` в Java-коде и задать это значение высоте всем 9 компоновкам `LinearLayout` (содержащим все эти `TextView`), а у `TextView` задать высоту `match_parent`. Получилось идеально и, по моему мнению, очень оптимально, так, как я и хотел. Я сейчас попробую разобраться в предложенном Вами методом решения проблемы, может всё круче получится.

Comment: p.s. я, кстати, забыл указать, что минимальная версия API у моего приложения - 15.